# How many games are there in the Two Worlds series?

Tags: two-worlds-2

I recently bought a game called Two Worlds II GOTY edition and I've taken a liking to it is the any more games in the series bar number 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 2 games in this series:

[Two Worlds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Worlds_%28video_game%29)

and

[Two Worlds II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Worlds_II)

Aside: The "GOTY" has also no legitimacy - no major media outlet declared it as Game of the year.

Comment: ahh Cheers are there any Dlcs for the first one?

Comment: Yes - [Tainted Blood](http://www.gamespot.com/two-worlds/dlc/202735/platform/xbox360/) and [Curse of Souls](http://www.gamespot.com/two-worlds/dlc/202734/platform/xbox360/)

Comment: okay thanks I will look for the first one aswell they seem to be good games I was surprised by it :)

Comment: He means the Velvet edition.  From the Wiki you linked for Two Worlds II: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Worlds_II#Game_of_the_Year_Edition